# Copy multiple sub-folders to one folder with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am new with PowerShell and I have small issue.

I have 2 folders on C:/ -- `C:/folder1` and `C:/folder2`

*folder1* contains 10 sub-folders, and I wants to copy only 3 of them to *folder2*.

I should do it with Remote Computer, so I should use `Invoke-Command` also.

Unfortunately, the program isn't works with my code.

```
$SubFolders = "C:/subfolder1", "C:/subfolder2", "C:/subfolder3"
$copy = InvokeCommand -ComputerName $compname | For-EachObject { Write-Host = "$SubFolders" }
$paste = "C:/folder2"
Copy-Item $copy $paste -Recurse -Force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $compname -ScriptBlock {param($folders,$paste) Copy-Item -Path $folders -Destination $paste} -ArgumentList $folders, $paste
```

Not the most elegant solution but it works.

Answer (score 1):

To Move or Copy Files in Multiple Sub-Folders to a Single Folder.

Open a Command Prompt window. Use the following command-line example.

```
cd /d "d:\snaps\2016"
for /r %d in (*) do copy "%d" "d:\My pictures"`
```

This recursively copies all files in the “snaps\2016” folder to the “My pictures” folder.

Or try this:

```
$Path = 'S:\powerrocket\0test' #Root path to look for files
$DestinationPath = "C:\powerrocket\0test\"

#Grab a recursive list of all subfolders
$SubFolders = dir $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.FullName}

#Iterate through the list of subfolders and grab the first file in each
ForEach ($Folder in $SubFolders) {
$FullFileName = dir $Folder | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object {$_.LastWriteTime} -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
Copy-Item -Path $FullFileName -Destination $DestinationPath -Force
}
```